# Child path same as parent path on angular 2, not showing child component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

i have a code like this

**app.routes.ts**

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full', data: { title: 'Login' } },
    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, pathMatch: 'full', data: { title: 'Register' } },
    { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent, pathMatch: 'full', data: { title: 'Forgot Password' } },
    { path: 'test', component: TestPopToasterComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        RegisterComponent,
        ForgotPasswordComponent,
    ];
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: false, preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }),
        MainModule,
        //other module
    ];
```

**main.routes.ts**

```
export const routes = [
  { path: '', component: MainComponent, children: [
    { path: '', loadChildren: './homepage/homepage.module#HomepageModule' },
    { path: 'product/:slug', loadChildren: './product/product.module#ProductModule' },
    { path: 'static/:slug', loadChildren: './static/static.module#StaticModule' },
  ]},
];
```

**main.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MainComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        FooterComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
        ProductModule,
        StaticModule,
        HomepageModule
    ]
})
export class MainModule {
    public static routes = routes;
 }
```

**homepage.router.ts**

```
export const routes = [
    { path: '', component: MainComponent, children: [
        { path: '', component: HomepageComponent }
    ]}
];
```

**homepage.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HomepageComponent,
        BannerComponent,
        BrandComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
        BrowserModule
    ]
})
export class HomepageModule {
    public static routes = routes;
}
```

**product.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ProductComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ]
})
export class ProductModule {
    public static routes = routes;
}
```

**product.router.ts**

```
export const routes = [
    { path: '', component: MainComponent, children: [
        { path: 'product/:slug', component: ProductComponent, data: { title: 'Product' } }
    ]}
];
```

**static.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        StaticComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ],
})
export class StaticModule {
    public static routes = routes;
}
```

**static.router.ts**

```
export const routes = [
    { path: '', component: MainComponent, children: [
        { path: 'static/:slug', component: StaticComponent,  pathMatch: 'full' },
    ]}
];
```

when i access ' ' it's only showing MainComponent

but when i access 'product/:slug' & 'static/:slug' it's showing MainComponent and child component

i don't know why, can you guys help me?

Comment: You're going to have to show a bit more code than this.

Comment: i have added some code

Comment: If mainModule is your AppModule use RouterModule.forRoot(routes) instead of forChild()

Comment: i have AppModule too, so i want to make 2 type of routes, the first one have a component like header & footer, the second one doesn't have header & footer

Comment: routes doesn't have header & footer is login, register, forgot-password
routes have header & footer will redirect to MainModule, i set header & footer inside main.component.html

Comment: @RayzalMuhammadAnwarSutarno can you provide example in Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: i already understand that children path and parent path cannot empty like that, atleast 1 path that's not empty